Different computer hardware give very different NIntegrate result?
This question is inspired by comments under my previous question.
Suppose two computers are running Mathematica with the same version "14.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" and all the NIntegrate options are set identically, only difference is their hardware such as CPU and GPU, could there be a scenario where NIntegrate returns completely different results, with one generating warnings likeNIntegrate::eincr  and very different results, while the other does not?
For example, you can run this code：
NIntegrate[Boole[10^11 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*η + p^2] >= 10^-14] 
           Boole[1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*η + p^2]*n >= 10^-15] 
           Boole[1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*η + p^2]*z >= 10^-15] 
           (1/Sqrt[ 1 + p^2 - 2 p*η]), 
           {η, -1, 1}, {p, 10^-14, 10^11}, 
           {x, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {m, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, 
           {n, x, 1/p}, {z, m, 1/p},  
           AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 5,  
           Exclusions -> 1 + p^2 - 2 p*η == 0]

In my compuer,this returns 1.1917:

Some active code farmers finds the result is 0.456126:


Hmm, it looks like I'm the black sheep here, because Wolfram Cloud also gives the same result as on your machine. It might be that I've messed with some settings once, but I don't remember it now.

@Domen. may not. I have tested for a numerical Integration on two different computers which have same version and Mathematica operations. They give different results. One of them have more error and is  difficult to handle.

@Domen Versions numbers same but different release dates, so they are probably not exactly the same versions. Also OP in the first example did not use the same options in both cases.

@azerbajdzan. Both release dates are on July 16 2024, I check Wolfram web https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/quick-revision-history/index.php.zh?source=footer#:~:text=Mathematic why do you say Versions numbers same but different release dates ?

NIntegrate is throwing error messages, so the results are unreliable.

@azerbajdzan  It is two pictures (not different expressions in same picture) in  this question come from different computers. The second computation in the first picture is different from the second computation in the second picture.

@ Sjoerd Smit. Yes, in that case  I try to increase  WorkingPrecision, MaxErrorIncreases, MinRecursion, MaxRecursion , neither is  suitable for  silence  warning.

@domen and OP: Have you guys turned on the "Allow the Wolfram System to access the Internet" and so on in Edit->Preferences? Some small updates (including small bug fixes) are done through paclet updates.

@xzczd: Thank you. I have updated paclet.

The command Integrate[(1/Sqrt[1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta]]), {\[Eta], -1, 1}, {p, 10^-14,    10^11}, {x, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {m, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {n, x, 1/p}, {z, m,    1/p}] outputs 1333333333333328000000000000007999999999999661333333333334667999999999\ 9979999999999999913333333333333729999999999999400000000000000399999999\ 9999999/80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\ 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, i.e. 1.66667*10^41.

@user64494: Yes，if you delete any Boole condition in this question ，you will get the same result whatever you handle singularity  with Exclusions -> 1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta] == 0  or Boole[1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta] > 0. When Boole condition doesn't appear , you can Integrate it exactly.
